# Using the alpha channel of a GeoTIFF in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, wms, geotiff-tiff, transparency-opacity

I want to publish a map as a WMS using GeoServer. The map consists of several layers each of which is a GeoTIFF containing RGB channels and an alpha channel. The images were edited in Photoshop and Georeferenced using ArcMap.

I can publish the GeoTIFFs but when I connect to the WMS in ArcMap, the transparency works very poorly or even not at all. When i load the source GeoTIFFs as layers everything works like a charm.

In the ResourceConfigurationPage of Geoserver i set the minRange of all bands to 0 and the maxRange to 255. I didn't change the layers style so it's still set to the standard "raster" SLD.

What do I need to do in order to get the transparency working properly?

Comment: Please, clarify the statement "When i load the source GeoTIFFs as layers everything works like a charm."

Comment: Moreover, can you paste the result of the gdalinfo for one of these images?